# Aptana 3 JavaScript Code Folding / Outline

Tags: javascript, aptana, folding

I have the simplest code possible.

```
function test() {

}

function anotherFunction() {

}
```

In the Eclipse JavaScript or Spket JavaScript editor, both of them will show me to folding points, one in front of each function. Yet in Aptana Studio 3.0.3 on Eclipse 3.7 Windows 7 x64, no matter what I do Aptana just doesn't even show me it can fold these two functions. Also outline is also always blank for whatever reason. I have fresh copy of Eclipse along with fresh copy of Aptana 3 installed. But it doesn't help.

Code folding in Aptana works on my mac, but outline view still shows blank.

Has anybody else experienced this and got any tips on solving it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I would never be able to figure this question out, but actually got it working lol.

Anyways the problem is Aptana would only fully enable their JavaScript editor if the project in question is of some kind of web nature, such as  Web, PHP, Python, Ruby, Rails. I got my idea/inspiration from  [this page](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries) The funny thing is, apparently org.eclispe.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature (which is the default if you create a JavaScript project in Eclipse) is not "web" enough for Aptana to enable its editor.

This is also the reason why it worked on mac but not Windows.